# How to see what headers a request would contain before sending that request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

So, my question may be very silly but is there a way to inspect what headers would each request contain before sending it. I am using selenium with python but the question is more shifted towards "is something like this possible" rather than "how can I do it using selenium with python"

**IMPORTANT** What I am looking for is a way to do that without sending the request. I know that you can easily do that after sending it but is there a way to inspect the headers of request before it being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Selenium Wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/), it is an extension of Selenium which add this functionality. To read the headers before the request actually gets sent, you can use an interceptor and abort the request after you have read/processed/printed the headers

After installing with pip (`pip install selenium-wire`), you can use the following:

```python
from seleniumwire import webdriver

def interceptor(request):
    print(request.headers) # <--- Print the headers that would be sent
    request.abort() # <---------- Abort the request so that it does not get sent.

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.request_interceptor = interceptor
driver.get("https://my.test.url.com")
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to send the request. What I need is to inspect the headers before the request is sent. Is that possible?

Comment: You can use an interceptor to intercept the request before it is fully made. Have updated my answer with instructions